# Install ffmpeg with applescript

Tags: xcode, ffmpeg, installation, applescript, homebrew

I'm trying to create an applescript that installs ffmpeg.  I have two issues.

- I want to install Xcode, homebrew, ffmpeg, node, grant permissions, and ffmpeg-progressbar-cli one at a time. Not all at once but in that order.  ffmpeg is dependant on xcode so it needs to wait before xcode is done installing.
- The command for homebrew requires `"` which applescript makes me change to a `'` before I can run it but in this case it doesn't work.

Here is the script I have so far.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "xcode-select --install && ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" && brew install ffmpeg && brew install node && sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin /usr/local/etc && npm install --global ffmpeg-progressbar-cli"
    activate
end tell
```

I tried this and it doesn't seem to work as intended.

```
tell application "Terminal"
        do script "sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin /usr/local/etc && xcode-select --install"
        display dialog "Select OK once Xcode has installed" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        do script "ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)""
        display dialog "Select OK once Homebrew has installed" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        do script "brew install ffmpeg"
        display dialog "Select OK once ffmpeg has installed" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        do script "brew install node"
        display dialog "Select OK once node has installed" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        do script "npm install --global ffmpeg-progressbar-cli"
        display dialog "Select OK once ffmpeg-bar has installed" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        activate
    end tell
```

For the second issue it needs to be

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

but applescript makes me change it to

`ruby -e '$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)'`

with single quote which doesn't work.

Help and suggestions apreciated!

Comment: Question: does this script require user interaction, or should it work automatically?

Comment: Automatically would be better

Comment: Xcode creates a problem though because unlike all the other installs it installs externally from terminal so it might require a user to select a dialog box when the installation is complete unless you know a way around that.

Comment: I'll have to play with it and see. Though I have to say, Xcode is a *huge* program to install just so you can have access to ffmpeg. Are you sure you need the entire thing, and not just one or two components? It seems absurd to me to take up 17 Gb of disk space (Xcode's current footprint) merely to install what I expect is no more than a 500 Mb utility.

Comment: Yeah... it's a pain but unfortunately xcode is required in his particular install.

Comment: Again, I'd like to know *why* you believe it's required. The issue I'm facing right now is that in order to test my solution I have to run the install myself, and I don't really want to (a) mess up my current Xcode install, or (b) wait the 30-45 minutes that doing a full install of Xcode would demand. I don't think anyone you distribute this to is going to want that either.

Comment: Could xcode be setup as an optional additional install? It is required for this situation but it could just be a separate install from the actionlist

Comment: Actually, it turns out that the --install option lets you just install the developer command line tools, so it's not too onerous. The problem I'm having right now is with installing Homebrew (the ruby script wants user interaction, but I think I can pipe in a response).  Give me a bit on this; I'm out of the house right now.

Comment: I'm having an issue with the ruby script. after some experimentation, I discovered that when I try to run it in terminal *without* administrator privileges I get a permissions error (when it tries to copy something out of the Xcode bundle), but when I try to run it *with* administrator privileges the script tells me I should not run it as root, and kills itself. I'm not sure how to resolve this 'dueling errors' issue.

Comment: I'm getting this error 
-e:1: `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name`
It looks like Terminal just doesn't like the single quote

Comment: Single quote?  I'm running `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` (no single quotes) and getting the fatal error "cannot copy '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/fsmonitor-watchman.sample' to '/usr/local/Homebrew/.git/hooks/fsmonitor-watchman.sample': Permission denied"

Comment: Script Editor will not let me execute this 
```
 tell application "Terminal"
  do script "/usr/bin/ruby -e "(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)""
  activate
 end tell
``` . It returns this error https://www.dropbox.com/s/1eikcqhfvnpfenw/error.png?dl=0

Comment: No, I meant that when I run that code directly in terminal — on the command line — I get errors. If the ***ruby*** code is buggy it doesn't matter what we do with AppleScript.

Comment: strange if i run 
```ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"``` i don't get any errors from terminal

Comment: What OS are you on, and what version of Xcode do you have?

Comment: Mojave 10.14.6 (18G2022) Xcode -Version 11.0 (11A420a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, try the following script, but see caveats below:

```
shellScriptHandler("xcode-select --install", false)
shellScriptHandler("sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar", true)
shellScriptHandler("ruby -e \"$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)\" <<< " & return, false)
shellScriptHandler("sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/var/homebrew /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions", true)
shellScriptHandler("/usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew install ffmpeg", false)
shellScriptHandler("/usr/local/Homebrew/bin/brew install node", false)
shellScriptHandler("sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin /usr/local/etc", true)
shellScriptHandler("/usr/local/bin/npm install --global ffmpeg-progressbar-cli", false)

on shellScriptHandler(command, usesAdmin)
    log command
    (*
        The try block catches any errors and reports them; the user can choose 
        to continue execution if it's a warning, or cancel execution outright.

        The 'eval' statement forces do shell script to read the standard
        interactive $PATH variable, so that it sees /user/local/, otherwise it 
        can't find the files it needs.
    *)
    try
        do shell script "eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`; " & command administrator privileges usesAdmin
    on error errstr
        display dialog errstr buttons {"Continue", "Cancel"} default button "Continue"
    end try
end shellScriptHandler
```

Caveats:

1. If there is a previous install of homebrew, the first line may fail with a permissions error; on my system, it tried to copy something from the Xcode bundle to /usr/local/Homebrew/.git/..., but needed root privileges. I solved that problem by deleting the folder /usr/local/Homebrew entirely, but that might be a bit drastic for the general case. You'll have to see if the problem recurs.
2. I added a couple of `chown` commands in lines 2 and 4. These popped up as errors when I ran the ruby script and `brew install...`. You may run across other such errors based on idiosyncrasies in different systems, but it shouldn't hurt to add more such commands to straighten out the permissions in /usr/local.
3. This script should run with a minimum of user interaction, but it does need the occasional 'ok' or password entry. Those *could* be automated, but I'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: I've tested it and it is working great.  Thanks again Ted!

Comment: For anyone who comes by this in the future I did discover this workaround for using " in this command `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737414/using-double-quotes-in-applescript-command-do-shell-script-echo . which makes the applescript command work: `do script "ruby -e \"$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)\"`  But Ted's solution is better.